# Why using System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping the Ping is not exist?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse
```

IPAddress is not exist since Ping is not exist.
I tried to add reference of System.Net didn't work.

My vs is on .net 4.5

Comment: Add `using System.Net;`

Answer (score 2):

[`IPAddress class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is under the `System.Net` namespace so you should import that namespace with:

```
using System.Net;
```

You already import `System.Net.NetworkInformation` but it is completely different namespace.